# How to plot a bar graph of decaying values?

Tags: diagrams

How would I draw a picture like this in tex?

I'm not sure of the scaling ratio. I believe it can be arbitrary. i.e. As long as the length of `$\ell_j$` is less than `$\ell_i$`, `$\forall \, j>i$`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular function, or just demonstrate a method?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Any method would be fine.

Comment: This seems almost trivial compared to the other diagrams you have requested. Have you studied the code in the other answers? If you get more specific in terms of which aspects you are having difficulty with, it would be a lot easier to help you where you can actually adapt it for future diagrams.

Comment: At least you could tell us the relation between line lengths.

Comment: @Ignasi I'm not sure of the scaling ratio. I believe it can be arbitrary. i.e. As long as the length of $\ell_j$ is less than $\ell_i$, $\forall \, j>i$.

Comment: Add Title + logic to generate figure in Q: `What is the name of figure` to help other's find easily and add the above logic/relation between the decay lines in Q ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With a TikZ `\foreach` loop it is just three lines. To control the decay change the part

```
... -- (\x,-10/\x);
```

to your liking, e.g.

```
... -- (\x,{-5/sqrt(\x)});
```

## Example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,11} {
        \draw[|-|] (\x,0) node[above] {$\ell_{\x}$} -- (\x,-10/\x);
    }
    \node at (12,-10/12/2) {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: How do you add the ellipses?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter See my updated answer. Keep in mind, that you might want to adjust the `y`-component of the ellipsis, if you adjust the decay.

Answer (score 7):

Done without `tikz`.  One passes a label and space-separated real-number list to `\graphmydata`.  Configurable parameters include the unit length (scale) associated with the data (`\graphunits`), the rule thickness (`\rlwd`), the horizontal gap between items (`\myhgap`), and the tick length (`\ticklength`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\def\myhgap{1.5em}
\def\ticklength{.5ex}
\newlength\graphunits
\graphunits 1cm
\def\tick{\rule{\ticklength}{\rlwd}}

\newcommand\dline[1]{%
  \setstackgap{S}{0pt}\Shortunderstack{\tick\\\rule[-#1]{\rlwd}{#1} \\\tick}}

\newcommand\mygraph[2]{%
  \stackunder[3pt]{\hsmash{#1}}{\dline{#2\graphunits}}\hspace{\myhgap}\ignorespaces}

\newcounter{index}
\def\graphmydata#1#2{%
  \readArrayij{#2}{datablock}{1}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\datablockCELLS}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \mygraph{$#1_{\theindex}$}{\arrayij{datablock}{\theindex}{1}}%
  }%
  \raisebox{-\baselineskip+5pt}{$\cdots$}%
}
\begin{document}
\graphmydata{l}{3 1.5 0.75 0.375 0.1875 0.09375}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, changing the parameters to

```
\def\rlwd{.8pt}
\def\myhgap{1.6em}
\def\ticklength{.8ex}
\graphunits 0.02cm
\graphmydata{p}{103.4 52.2 26.6 13.8 7.4 4.2 2.6 1.8 1.4 1.2 1}
```

yields

[image]

---

EDIT: for those wishing to import data from a file, rather than from a `\def`, the `readarray` package can import the data from a file.  Here is that version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\def\myhgap{1.5em}
\def\ticklength{.5ex}
\newlength\graphunits
\graphunits 1cm
\def\tick{\rule{\ticklength}{\rlwd}}

\newcommand\dline[1]{%
  \setstackgap{S}{0pt}\Shortunderstack{\tick\\\rule[-#1]{\rlwd}{#1} \\\tick}}

\newcommand\mygraph[2]{%
  \stackunder[3pt]{\hsmash{#1}}{\dline{#2\graphunits}}\hspace{\myhgap}\ignorespaces}

\newcounter{index}
\def\graphmydatafile#1#2{%
  \readdef{#2}{\mydata}%
  \readArrayij{\mydata}{datablock}{1}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\datablockCELLS}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \mygraph{$#1_{\theindex}$}{\arrayij{datablock}{\theindex}{1}}%
  }%
  \raisebox{-\baselineskip+5pt}{$\cdots$}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{mydatafile.dat}
3
1.5
0.75
0.375
0.1875
0.09375%
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\graphmydatafile{l}{mydatafile.dat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Done with MetaPost, and the `gmp` package as interface (to be run with the shell-escape option activated).

There are noticeably more lines than with `tikz`, mainly because I had to define myself a macro that draws the segments with perpendicular marks at their extremities, since MetaPost has no build-in macro for that. Yet it was no big deal. Anyway, MetaPost is by nature more verbose than `tikz`, `pstricks` of its related (La)TeX package `mfpic`, but defining auxiliary macros with it when needed is fortunately easy (at least I find it so)).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latex, shellescape]{gmp}
\gmpoptions{everymp={%
  input latexmp;
  setupLaTeXMP(options="12pt", textextlabel = enable, mode = rerun);
  % mark length
  lmark := 6bp;
  % auxiliary macro for segments with marks at their extremities
  vardef segment(expr A, B) =
    save v; pair v; v = 0.5lmark*unitvector(B-A) rotated 90;
    image(draw A--B; for M = A, B: draw M+v -- M-v; endfor;)
  enddef;
  % function defining the length of the segments (borrowed from Henri Menke)
  vardef f(expr x) = -10/x enddef;}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{mpost*}
    u := 1cm; n := 11;
    for i= 1 upto n-1:
      draw segment(u*(i, 0), u*(i, f(i)));
      label.top("$\ell_{" & decimal(i) & "}$", u*(i, 0));
    endfor;
    label("$\ldots$", u*(n, 0.5f(n)));
  \end{mpost*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to write a custom `segment` function: if you set `ahangle:=180; ahlength:=3` then you can use `drawdblarrow` to make the bars.

Answer (score 4):

No fun without PSTricks. The following is the most optimized PSTricks solution. Can you do more?

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[arrows=|-|](0,-11)(13,1)
    \foreach \i in {1,...,11}{\uput[90](\i,0){$l_{\i}$}\psline(\i,0)(*{\i} {-10/x})}
    \rput(*12 {-5/x}){\ldots}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\SpecialCoor` and `pgfmath` and `multido` should be available by default I think!

Comment: Just to know: When does one need to use `pgf` packages while working with PSTricks code ? There should always be an equivalent package in both right ?

Comment: @texenthusiast: `pgfmath` is a multipurpose package that can be used for both PSTricks and TikZ and others. If it is used together with `pgffor`, it allows us to use `\foreach \x[count=\c from 1]...` that is useful in some PSTrics cases. I think PSTricks maintainers forgot to include `pgfmath` while `pgffor` is already loaded by default.